# Android EMM: Enable the System apps for the owner user

Tags: android, android-source, android-for-work, android-management-api, android-enterprise

I need to enable some of the system apps of Android for the managed google play account. I am wirting the neccasary things like package names of those apps in the Device policy. Then I am provisioning my device with the policy but it does not show the system apps I required.

In the Settings it is showing me the System apps but with that it display message "Not installed for the user owner".

So, is there any way of enabling the system apps for the managed play accounts?

Device policy:

```
{
"applications": [{
        "packageName": "com.example.ic.systemapp",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "lockTaskAllowed": true,
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.example.homelauncher",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.android.cts.priv.ctsshim",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.qualcomm.qti.auth.sampleextauthservice",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.android.providers.telephony",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.android.providers.calendar",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.android.providers.media",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.android.wallpapercropper",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.android.documentsui",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.oem.camera",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.android.externalstorage",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.android.htmlviewer",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.qualcomm.svi",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.android.quicksearchbox",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.android.providers.downloads",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.qualcomm.qti.auth.sampleauthenticatorservice",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.android.messaging",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.qualcomm.qti.auth.fidocryptoservice",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.android.defcontainer",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.android.providers.downloads.ui",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.android.pacprocessor",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.qualcomm.cabl",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "honeywell.hedc_demoapp",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.android.certinstaller",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.android.carrierconfig",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "org.codeaurora.bluetooth",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.oem.engineeringmode",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.android.egg",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.android.mtp",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.android.stk",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.android.backupconfirm",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.android.provision",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "org.codeaurora.ims",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.android.statementservice",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.android.calendar",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.qualcomm.qti.auth.secureextauthservice",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.qualcomm.qcrilmsgtunnel",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.android.providers.settings",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.android.sharedstoragebackup",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.oem.log",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.android.printspooler",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.android.dreams.basic",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.android.frameworks.telresources",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.android.webview",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.android.inputdevices",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.estrongs.android.pop",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.qualcomm.qti.auth.securesampleauthservice",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.qualcomm.qti.CdmaCallOptions",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.qti.dpmserviceapp",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.qti.xdivert",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.android.musicfx",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.android.cellbroadcastreceiver",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "android.ext.shared",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.android.onetimeinitializer",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.qualcomm.qti.simsettings",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.android.server.telecom",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.android.keychain",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.example.secure",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.android.printservice.recommendation",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.android.dialer",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "android.ext.services",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.android.calllogbackup",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.android.packageinstaller",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "org.codeaurora.btmultisim",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.svox.pico",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.dsi.ant.server",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.example.peripheral",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.android.proxyhandler",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.android.inputmethod.latin",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "org.chromium.webview_shell",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.android.managedprovisioning",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.android.dreams.phototable",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.android.smspush",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.android.wallpaper.livepicker",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.example.demo",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.android.storagemanager",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.android.bookmarkprovider",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.qualcomm.qti.ims",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.android.calculator2",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.qualcomm.location",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.oem.engineeringmode.touch",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.hemaperipheraltestapp",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.qualcomm.qti.tetherservice",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.oem.engineeringmode.mxtupdate",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.qualcomm.qti.securemsm.mdtp",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.android.vpndialogs",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.example.mocklocation",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.android.music",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.android.phone",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.android.wallpaperbackup",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    }
],
"screenCaptureDisabled": false,
"cameraDisabled": false,
"keyguardDisabledFeatures": [
    "TRUST_AGENTS"
],
"defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT",
"addUserDisabled": false,
"adjustVolumeDisabled": false,
"factoryResetDisabled": false,
"installAppsDisabled": false,
"mountPhysicalMediaDisabled": false,
"modifyAccountsDisabled": false,
"safeBootDisabled": true,
"uninstallAppsDisabled": true,
"statusBarDisabled": false,
"keyguardDisabled": true,
"statusReportingSettings": {
    "applicationReportsEnabled": true,
    "deviceSettingsEnabled": true,
    "softwareInfoEnabled": true,
    "memoryInfoEnabled": true,
    "networkInfoEnabled": true,
    "displayInfoEnabled": true,
    "powerManagementEventsEnabled": true,
    "hardwareStatusEnabled": true
},
"bluetoothContactSharingDisabled": false,
"wifiConfigsLockdownEnabled": true,
"bluetoothConfigDisabled": false,
"cellBroadcastsConfigDisabled": false,
"credentialsConfigDisabled": false,
"mobileNetworksConfigDisabled": false,
"tetheringConfigDisabled": false,
"vpnConfigDisabled": false,
"wifiConfigDisabled": false,
"createWindowsDisabled": false,
"networkResetDisabled": false,
"outgoingBeamDisabled": false,
"outgoingCallsDisabled": false,
"removeUserDisabled": false,
"shareLocationDisabled": false,
"smsDisabled": false,
"unmuteMicrophoneDisabled": false,
"usbFileTransferDisabled": false,
"ensureVerifyAppsEnabled": true,
"stayOnPluggedModes": [
    "AC"
],
"setUserIconDisabled": false,
"setWallpaperDisabled": false,
"dataRoamingDisabled": false,
"locationMode": "HIGH_ACCURACY",
"networkEscapeHatchEnabled": true,
"bluetoothDisabled": false,
"blockApplicationsEnabled": false,
"installUnknownSourcesAllowed": true,
"debuggingFeaturesAllowed": true,
"funDisabled": false,
"autoTimeRequired": true,
"appAutoUpdatePolicy": "APP_AUTO_UPDATE_POLICY_UNSPECIFIED",
"kioskCustomLauncherEnabled": true,
"skipFirstUseHintsEnabled": true,
"privateKeySelectionEnabled": true,
"encryptionPolicy": "ENCRYPTION_POLICY_UNSPECIFIED",
"usbMassStorageEnabled": true,
"permissionGrants": [{
        "permission": "android.permission_group.CALENDAR,android.permission_group.CAMERA",
        "policy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "permission": "android.permission_group.CAMERA",
        "policy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "permission": "android.permission_group.CONTACTS",
        "policy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "permission": "android.permission_group.LOCATION",
        "policy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "permission": "android.permission_group.MICROPHONE",
        "policy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "permission": "android.permission_group.SENSORS",
        "policy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "permission": "android.permission_group.STORAGE",
        "policy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "permission": "android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED",
        "policy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
        "permission": "android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE",
        "policy": "GRANT"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Can you provide your code for enabling the system apps? Is your app a profile owner or device owner? How do you provision your device (i.e. NFC, qr code)? Are you disabling all system apps during provisioning?

Comment: I am provisioning the device using qr code method. My system app is not a profile owner or the device owner.  I have written the device policy which should enable the necessary system apps.

Comment: Is it correct that you are using Android Management APIs? Have you tried including this in your QR code? "android.app.extra.EXTRA_PROVISIONING_LEAVE_ALL_SYSTEM_APPS_ENABLED": true,

Comment: @SteveMiskovetz Added the device policy in the question.

Comment: No. I have not included this flag in the QR code. Let me try it.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used Android Management API yet so I can't tell you how to include it using Google's workflow. You could try creating your own QR code by reading what Google creates for you, putting the data in a QR code generator like: https://www.qr-code-generator.com/#text and then adding this line including the "true":   
 "android.app.extra.EXTRA_PROVISIONING_LEAVE_ALL_SYSTEM_APPS_ENABLED": true

Comment: Yeah.. I have done the same and now trying it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi @SteveMiskovetz, I haven't got success by adding this flag in the QR code bundle data. But, I have made the changes to the AOSP codebase to use this flag and it worked for me. Thank you for your help.